# Парсинг RSS на Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rss

Нужно отобразить на сайте текст статьи из RSS ленты: http://www.zol.ru/z-news/lastnews.php 
Использую следующий код:

```
$.ajax({
  url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(FEED_URL),
  dataType : 'json',
  success  : function (data) {
    if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + e.title);
        console.log("author     : " + e.published);
        console.log("description: " + e.description);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Дату, название статьи и ссылку вытащить удалось, но вот сам текст статьи, поле

```
<yandex:full-text>...</yandex:full-text>
```

понятия не имею как вытащить.

Руководство по Google Feed API тоже особо не помогло.
https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide?hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, надо бы наверное работать не с `json`, а с `xml`. Или даже со смешанным контентом, так как в `json` ответе данное поле просто напросто не присылается.

Не знаю как через аякс, но по документации, что вы дали (по гугл документации) получается так:

```js
 google.load("feeds", "1");
     
        
function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.zol.ru/z-news/lastnews.php");
  feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
  feed.load(function(result) {    
    if (!result.error) { 
      //console.log(result);
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var e = result.feed.entries[i];
        var xmlNode = result.xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('item')[i];

        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + e.title);
        console.log("author     : " + e.author);
        console.log("description: " + xmlNode.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        console.log(xmlNode.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://news.yandex.ru', '*')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

      }
    }
  });
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Но, что-то сам парсер этот работает не очень корректно. Потому, что данным способом он возвращает только четыре элемента.

В общем, наверное, стоит подумать о каком-либо другом парсере `rss`. Но в любом случае для того, чтобы вынуть именно `yandex:fulltext` придется работать с данными как с `xml` или микс контентом. В качестве `json` вряд ли хоть один парсер вам вынет данные из `yandex:fulltext`